# Get the user object from session

Tags: python, django, authentication

How can I get the user object that login() has save in the session?

```
user= request.session.get('user')
```

returns nothingIn this example:

```
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if user is not None:
    if user.is_active:
        login(request, user)
```

Comment: request = request.user maybe?

Comment: please read about the django.contrib.auth.models.User object

Comment: your first example is NOT how you you get the user. look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/auth/#authentication-in-web-requests have you done the example app Django offers?

Comment: request = request.user doesn't return anything but exception

Comment: @hin, do you have the middleware installed?https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**AuthenticationMiddleware** adds the user attribute, representing the currently-logged-in user, to every incoming HttpRequest object. Authentication middleware requires session middleware to be installed. So, you should add this middlewares in settings.py to MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES tuple:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = ( 
    #...
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    #...
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have '`django.contrib.auth`' and '`django.contrib.contenttypes`' in your installed apps. run syncdb if needed after. Now you will have all the user tables you need.

Next you want to make sure you have request.user on every request. I think this is why your not getting anything with request.user.  `SessionMiddleware` and `AuthenticationMiddleware` middlewares needs to be in your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in settings.

For more info read the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/)